# Selenium 3+Python: Import error: there isn't module named 'page'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, импорт, page

Добрый вечер изучаю автоматизацию. По этим урокам [Python bindings documentation for selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html)

6.1. Test case

```
import page
```

выкидывает ошибку :

> ImportError: No module named 'page'

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему?

[image: Структура моего проекта]

Comment: А page это что за модуль, откуда ему взяться? Может быть, вы не установили Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

В документации, ссылку на которую Вы предоставили, в следующем абзаце указано, что нужно создать файл page.py

6.2. Page object classes

The page object pattern intends creating an object for each web page. By following this technique a layer of separation between the test code and technical implementation is created.

The page.py will look like this:

```
from element import BasePageElement
from locators import MainPageLocators

class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement):
    """This class gets the search text from the specified locator"""

    #The locator for search box where search string is entered
    locator = 'q'


class BasePage(object):
    """Base class to initialize the base page that will be called from all pages"""

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class MainPage(BasePage):
    """Home page action methods come here. I.e. Python.org"""

    #Declares a variable that will contain the retrieved text
    search_text_element = SearchTextElement()

    def is_title_matches(self):
        """Verifies that the hardcoded text "Python" appears in page title"""
        return "Python" in self.driver.title

    def click_go_button(self):
        """Triggers the search"""
        element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)
        element.click()


class SearchResultsPage(BasePage):
    """Search results page action methods come here"""

    def is_results_found(self):
        # Probably should search for this text in the specific page
        # element, but as for now it works fine
        return "No results found." not in self.driver.page_source
```